# Performance of pthread_mutex_lock/unlock

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, mutex

I've noticed that I take a pretty big performance hit when I have an algorithm that locks and unlocks a thread ALOT.

Is there any way to help this overhead? Would using a semaphore be more/less efficient?

Thanks

```
typedef struct _treenode{
   struct _treenode *leftNode;
   struct _treenode *rightNode;
   int32_t data;
   pthread_mutex_t mutex;
}TreeNode;

pthread_mutex_t _initMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int32_t insertNode(TreeNode **_trunk, int32_t data){
   TreeNode **current;
   pthread_mutex_t *parentMutex = NULL, *currentMutex = &_initMutex;

   if(_trunk != NULL){
      current = _trunk;
      while(*current != NULL){
         pthread_mutex_lock(&(*current)->mutex);
         currentMutex = &(*current)->mutex;
         if((*current)->data < data){
            if(parentMutex != NULL)
               pthread_mutex_unlock(parentMutex);
            pthreadMutex = currentMutex;
            current = &(*current)->rightNode;
         }else if((*current)->data > data){
            if(parentMutex != NULL)
               pthread_mutex_unlock(parentMutex);
            parentMutex = currentMutex;
            current = &(*current)->leftNode;
         }else{
            pthread_mutex_unlock(currentMutex);
            if(parentMutex != NULL)
               pthread_mutex_unlock(parentMutex);
            return 0;
         }
      }
      *current = malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
      pthread_mutex_init(&(*current)->mutex, NULL);
      pthread_mutex_lock(&(*current)->mutex);
      (*current)->leftNode = NULL;
      (*current)->rightNode = NULL;
      (*current)->data = data;
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&(*current)->mutex);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(currentMutex);
   }else{
      return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}

int main(){
   int i;
   TreeNode *trunk = NULL;
   for(i=0; i<1000000; i++){
      insertNode(&trunk, rand() % 50000);
   }
}
```

Comment: A semaphore does different (more complex) things and is more likely slower.  What's your OS?  Can you make the lock finer-grain so you don't block for as long?

Comment: Or make them more coarse grained/do more work per locking, so you don't get so many context switches. There's a fine balance.

Comment: If you show/describe the algorithm we might give hints. The solution should be: use less locking (divide the work on dedicated cores, so you don't need to lock the subregions) or make it lockfree (haaaaaaard). Nothing else but Moores Law is going to help

Comment: SOme algorithms are inherently more serial than others. But locking and restricting access to get a correct result is better than not locking and getting an incorrect result quicker.

Comment: @nos - good point, thanks for that.  One golden rule: don't lock across long-running ops like network or file I/O if you can help it.

Comment: @Steve, not sure about your first comment, I've always found semaphores to be a more lightweight synchronisation mechanism - however it doesn't mean that it's necessarily the correct answer here...

Comment: Posted code... Basically, its a binary tree... This function just inserts a node.

Comment: @Nim - agreed, it's going to be platform-dependent.  This code looks like it's too lock-happy, anyway.

Comment: So does anyone have a better algorithm to keep this thread safe?  Currently, it looks like the best way is to just lock at the beginning of the thread and unlock at return.

Comment: 1) You're locking your freshly allocated object, which would be by no means necessary if you wouldn't place it into the tree immediately. 2) There's a typo I think where you set `pthreadMutex`; it should read `parentMutex`. 3) Your overlapping top-down locking strategy bears the risk of a deadlock should you ever traverse the tree in the opposite direction. 4) I'm not sure you're actually achieving what you were after with your overlapping parent/child locking; you'd have to present a list of allowed operations. 5) If the tree can get huge, use single RWLock for tree, but see my other comment.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of worrying about the blades of grass, step back and observe the whole forest.

Any algorithm which depends on two threads potentially closely stepping on each each other's toes is inherently inefficient.  Try to find a way to drastically reduce the need for interaction.

For example, if one thread produces data and the other consumes it, one can easily think up an inefficient algorithm where the producer publishes the data in shared memory and then waits for the other to consume it.  Meanwhile the consumer is waiting for the producer to finish, etc., etc.  This is all much simplified by the producer writing into a file or pipe, and the consumer reading from it.

Answer (score 15):

`pthread_mutex_lock` and `pthread_mutex_unlock` vary in cost depending on contention:

1. Single thread use - either only one thread exists, or only one thread is using the mutex and the resource it protects: locking is **virtually free**, perhaps 80-100 cycles at most.
2. Multiple threads using the resource, but locks are held for very short intervals and contention is rare: locking has some cost, and it's hard to measure; the cost consists mostly of invalidating other cores'/cpus' cache lines.
3. Significant lock contention: nearly every lock and unlock operation will require assistance from the kernel, and the cost is easily several thousand (possibly even tens of thousand) cycles per lock/unlock.

Still, mutexes should be the least expensive locking primitive in most situations and on most implementations. Occasionally spinlocks may perform better. I would never expect semaphores to perform better.

Comment: In some contexts, 80-100 cycles is not "virtually free".

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify: I was comparing it to a pair of trivial external function calls, i.e. the performance you'd get if `pthread_mutex_lock` and `pthread_mutex_unlock` were near-empty functions (but still can't be inlined and still setup a stack frame). I don't have figures in front of me, but I think the "no-op locks" case will get close to 80 cycles, except maybe on high-end x86 machines.

Comment: For a simple producer/consumer based on an atomic ring, a semaphore signalling when there is data available can outperform a condition variable / mutex as for the latter the producers need to also lock to change the condition.

Comment: @CashCow: My remark about semaphores was in reference to using a binary semaphore as a lock. My intuition is that this should, at best, match the performance of a mutex, but might also be somewhat worse. In particular, POSIX semaphores have some properties that might make them more costly -- ability to act on cancellation, requirement that the post operation be async-signal-safe (which limits implementation choices), etc. Also, while the next issue of POSIX might loosen mutex requirements to permit acquire/release semantics, semaphores will almost surely remain "seq_cst".

Answer (score 8):

As far as I can see your lock strategy is not optimal since most of the locks will not be taken to change the data, but just to read and find the way through the tree.

`pthread_rwlock_t` *could* help on this. You'd only take read-locks on the path down in the tree until you hit a node where you want to do some modification. There you would then take a write-lock. By that you could have other threads perform the same task when walking down the tree in a different branch without disturbing each other.

A decent implementation of `pthread_rwlock_t` would do this with a counter for the readers that it changes with atomic operations, as long as there is no contention with writers. This should be very fast. Once there is contention, it would be as costly as a mutex, I think.

Comment: @Andrew, sorry its `pthread_rwlock_t`. And it should just be there in `<pthread.h.` if it is implemented on your system.

Comment: @Andrew and Jens. 1) RWLocks are not always a better solution. If all read operations take very short and all write operations take long, their overhead as compared to MutEx can easily kill their conceptual benefit. It depends on the number of readers and writers and how often they hit the section in parallel. 2) As far as I know, RWLocks are built on top of MutExes, but even if not, they're more expensive than MuitExes. 3) I'd use a single RWLock for the whole tree if writing occurs rarely. Then, all the readers can get happy in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Your locks are probably too fine-grained. Of course, the optimal granularity may vary depending on workload.

You could use a single lock for the whole tree, and it *may* perform better. But, if you do lots of reading and relatively few insertions/deletions, you end up with the whole tree locked often for no good reason. You may want to use a reader-writer lock, which would allow several readers at the same time.

Your question reminded me of [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002717/thread-safe-sorted-linked-list), when there is a comparison between fine-grained locking and coarse-grained locking for a linked list. While in the coarse-grained version each thread run in turn (not in parallel), and the total running time was slightly more than the sum of each thread's running time, and in the fine-grained version total running time was much less than the sum of each thread's running time, the added overhead of fine-grained locking totally offset these benefit, making the fine-grained version slower than the coarse-grained one.

Answer (score 0):

Locking and unlocking are very expensive operations in the case of pthread_mutex_lock/unlock. With more details on the algorithm I could make some suggestions but as far as I can tell I can't tell you anything for certain. Semaphores are an alternative (again depending on the algorithm) and also barriers are another useful method for concurrency. To help the overhead you can do things like either make your locks smaller granularity or greater granularity. locks inside loops that iterate multiple times are a bad idea and you may want to move them outside the loop. This is just one example but there are probably more I can come up with. It's about determining whether the cost of the lock is greater than that of the critical section of your code. If you provide your algorithm or some sample code I'd be glad to take a look at it.

Comment: He did mention pthread_mutex_lock/unlock which are quite expensive, although you are correct I should edit my answer to only encompass pthread_mutex_lock/unlock as CriticalSection is relatively quick as are Boost locks. I also suggested he post some code and some things he could do to change the locked section to improve performance.

Answer (score -4):

pthread_mutex_lock and pthread_cond_wait are OS primitives - they put calling thread into sleep, transferring control to another thread. I.e. they involve syscalls and a lot of overhead. In tight integration between two threads, you don't really want to relinquish any control for even a cycle.

Give that I suggest using `volatile int` variables instead of mutexes:

```
volatile int data_ready = 0;
/*  ... */
while (!data_ready);
process_data();
data_ready = 0;
```